# How to model coiled cable

Tags: modeling, modifiers, rigging

Hi im new to blender (started about a month ago) im trying to make a coiled cable for my so called imaginary "desk setup"

Heres what im trying to make

[image]

Ive tried using screw modifier but the thing is I dont know how to make it like a cable as you need the ends to not be coiled. I searched all over the internet on how to make this but i cant find them.

If you could just direct me to what I could do and explain in detail so that i can follow step by step on how to do this.

Extra, and if, just if you can help me with rigging the cable so that I can move it around to make it more natural in the scene, example photo below:

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickly use a screw modifier for the basic shape.

[image: Screwed cable]

You could use a curve to make the second step easier - the extra objects addon will let you add a screwed curve.

Then just create the tail parts. I applied the screw modifier then I extruded but if you had used a path it would probably be easier

[image: Tail added to the screw]

I copied and flipped the whole thing, using snapping to add it to the top of itself, thus making the top tail.

[image: Both ends complete]

Then put the whole thing on a curve using a curve modifier.

[image: Curving cable]

Comment: Hey @J_M thankyou for replying! but im still stuck after the screw modifier, how do you have your screw to have its own vertices? i can only get them like this
https://imgur.com/sMQWiuW

Comment: Added the detail sorry. Just apply your screw modifier. Id recommend using a lower resolution circle (less verts) as you'll probably want to add a subsurf to make it all smoother.

Comment: OHHHH. sorry i didnt know what the apply button does! thankyou very much!