# Spiral filament with straight ends

Tags: modeling

Please see attached.

[image]

Making a spiral coil with straight/centered ends. To attach ends I used Bend but can't get a good fit to the spiral coil to make it look like one "filament". Another approach/idea?

Comment: Could you use a curve to model the spiral?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177343/how-to-model-coiled-cable