# How to go about making a keyring?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

[image]

how would i go about creating a keyring like this in blender? I started with a bezier circle curve but not sure how to make the double ring from there and have them connect at the center. thanks

Comment: Consider an Addon in User Preferences that creates a Spiral Curve. Search Curve.  Create the spiral of your choice. Then use the curve panel to create a cylindrical ,  or fancier cross section to your curve.   Please show you work as a Blender Screen capture.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42131/modelling-a-spiral-around-a-sphere

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177343/how-to-model-coiled-cable